# I can't get text to interact with an image properly and it is causing me to create many breakpoints in order for it to display properly

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have an image of a soundman holding a boom that slides in from the left on my index page. In order to have the text underneath the boom, I have the text and the image on different axes. There is something problematic when it comes to different screen sizes because the text moves up and down quite a bit depending on the screen size which can create an overlap with the image of the boom. I was in the process of creating multiple breakpoints (oh my god there are so many) when I thought maybe there would be a better way to have the text and the image all adjust in relation to each other.

codepen: https://codepen.io/arpunk/pen/vYLbvOG

site: [www.productionsound.net](http://www.productionsound.net)

Is there a better way to code the image/text?

Pasted the appropriate code below but the full code/html is on codepen

Thank you!

```
.mainwrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
}

.mainlogo {
  position: absolute;
  left: -100%;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation: slide 0.5s forwards;
  animation-delay: .5s;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.mainlogoname {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-size: 140%;
width: 58%;
height: auto;
line-height: 25px;
position: absolute;
top: 350px;
left: 37%;
z-index: -1;
padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `vw` unit, you can set the `top` position based on the width of the browser viewport. Then you can have the text move up and down as the image shrinks and grows, and you only need one media query to make it stay put when the image reaches its full size.

[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/TrevinAvery/pen/mdVvZYV)

```
.mainlogoname {
  top: calc(100px + 20vw);
  left: 38%;
}

@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  .mainlogoname {
    top: 330px;
  }
}
```

See [CSS-Tricks: Fun with Viewport Units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) for more info on the `vw` unit.

Comment: Thank you that's wonderful! Why are you calculating using 100px+20vw as opposed to only supplying a vw value?

Comment: With only `vw` it seemed to shift too much. By adding the calc, the shift is much smaller. Basically, I thought it looked better.